# NATS-Streaming record and re-stream channel messages

Tags: streaming, nats-streaming-server

I want to record messages streamed by NATS-streaming channel and stream it again when I want.

I want to create infrastructure to test my micro-service app. 
All micro-services are talking to each other using NATS-streaming and I would like to "record" stream of data, clean my database and stream it again to test if the system is consistent.

I saw that there is configuration for file-store or SQL-store but both are for storing the current state of NATS as described in the documentation. Also, I didn't find a way to "stream again" that data.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When messages are published, they are stored in the channel (message log) they are published to. You can then start subscriptions that point to any sequence/time in that channel and replay messages. As for persistence, there is support for memory, file and SQL stores.

More on documentation:

[Message logs](https://docs.nats.io/nats-streaming-concepts/channels/message-log)

[Subscriptions](https://docs.nats.io/nats-streaming-concepts/channels/subscriptions)

[Store implementations](https://docs.nats.io/nats-streaming-server/configuring/persistence)